# gitlab what is the FQDN of my host

Tags: gitlab, fqdn

I am trying to install Gitlab on a mac server 10.8.  I follow a procedure and when talking about configure Gitlab they ask to change "gitlab.example.com" to the FQDN of your host serving gitlab.

To get this do I need to type : hostname and make change in the gitlab.yml ?

Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, as in "[How can I find the domain (fqdn) for my machine if hostname doesn't return domain info and domainname returns empty?](https://serverfault.com/a/499900/783)":

```
host `hostname`
host `hostname` | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\ .*/\1/'
```

Or you could try using your ip address.

Answer (score 0):

The FQDN is the base url you're pointing to the server, e.g. http:example.com as opposed to http:example.com/subdirectory/
An easy way to see it if you already have one is to type `less /etc/hostname`
If you don't have a hostname, you definitely should have an IP address, you could also use your IP instead of the hostname.